# Adding effects to make voice sound like it’s over a telephone

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I understand that when a person speaks over a telephone, he sounds a bit different because of the frequency response of the microphone/channel/speaker being used.

I have been playing with speech signal processing in Python.
I was wondering how simulate this effect. Do I need to design a filter?

Comment: A fuzzbox nicely emulates the effect of telephone transmission.  Basically, the poor dynamic of the circuit forces the waveform to square instead of sinus.  (Sorry if my terminology is off here.)

Comment: As this question is more about signal processing than coding, you might want to re-ask or move this question to dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: You need two filters for the audio stream, 
Apply a "lowpass filter" set to 3000Hz / 12dB per octave
then apply a "highpass filter" set to 300Hz / 12 dB per octave

Comment: This http://mpastell.com/2010/01/18/fir-with-scipy/ with this http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/beginner-attempting-fft-signal-filtering-with-numpy should probably be help on the way. Too much for me to learn audio processing right now.

Comment: @deinonychusaur Those articles were a big help, i wrote a band pass filter of [300-3000Hz]/12dB per octave as suggested by John Woods.
The modified audio sounds like from a telephone, but not exactly.
I guess i'll have to play with it for a little longer. Cheers!
Thanks.

Comment: Great would really like to see your solution when you are done. Not every day one gets to answer your own question.

Comment: What John Woods refers to could nicely be performed with [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) from the command-line (and of course be called by Python too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code. Works fine for me:

```
from scipy.signal import lfilter, butter
from scipy.io.wavfile import read,write
from numpy import array, int16
import sys

def butter_params(low_freq, high_freq, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = low_freq / nyq
    high = high_freq / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, low_freq, high_freq, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_params(low_freq, high_freq, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fs,audio = read(sys.argv[1])
    low_freq = 300.0
    high_freq = 3000.0
    filtered_signal = butter_bandpass_filter(audio, low_freq, high_freq, fs, order=6)
    fname = sys.argv[1].split('.wav')[0] + '_moded.wav'
    write(fname,fs,array(filtered_signal,dtype=int16))
```

Comment: Hi, got back to check this one and realized `sr` is not defined in the `write` line (also `butter_bandpass_filter` != `butter_bandpassFilter`.